# Fix yaxis in place

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt, scrollbar

Here is some code I've written/adapted, which produces the output below it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import sys

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax
        self.on = 1
        self.lastline, = self.ax.plot([0],[0])
        self.cid = ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        self.on *=-1
        thisline = event.artist
        xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
        ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind
        print(xdata[ind])
        print('modified',xdata[ind][0])
        self.lastline.remove()
        self.lastline=self.ax.axvline(x=xdata[ind][0])
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

class View(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(View, self).__init__()

        self.initScene(5)

    def initScene(self,h):     

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.03,right=1,bottom=.1,top=1,wspace=0, hspace=0)

        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_xlim([0,1000])
        data = np.random.rand(1000)
        ax.plot(data, '-') 

        self.canvas.draw()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addWidget(self.canvas)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 700, 550) 

        self.view = View()
        self.view.setGeometry(0,0,self.width()*2,500)
        self.view.canvas.setGeometry(0,0,self.width()*2,500)        

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

[image]

I can use the scrollbar on the bottom to view the entire image. However, when scrolling, I quickly lose sight of the y-axis labels. Would it be possible to fix them in place, so that the scrollbar only changes the part of the xaxis that's visible (whilst the yaxis ticks and labels stay fixed)?

Comment: You cannot use the scrollbar of the QGraphicsScene to do that. You would need to implement a scrollbar and connect it to a function which updates the limits of the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scolling the complete figure inside a QGraphicsView one may rather add a `QScrollBar` to the window and connect it to a function, which updates the xlim of the axes inside the figure.

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Fig(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.factor = kwargs.pop("factor", 2)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, Figure(), *args,**kwargs)
        self.plot()
        self.scroll = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.scroll.actionTriggered.connect(self.updateFromScroll)

    def plot(self):
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        data = np.random.rand(1000)
        self.ax.plot(data, '-')
        self.xmin,self.xmax = self.ax.get_xlim()
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.xmin, self.xmax/float(self.factor))


    def updateFromScroll(self, evt):
        v = self.scroll.value()
        a = [self.xmin, self.xmax/float(self.factor)]
        lim = a+v/100.*np.diff(a)[0]
        self.ax.set_xlim(lim)
        self.draw_idle()


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):


        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.widget.layout().setSpacing(0)

        self.canvas = Fig()
        self.canvas.draw()


        self.nav = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.widget)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.nav)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.canvas.scroll)

        self.show()


qapp = QApplication([])
# pass the figure to the custom window
a = Window()
exit(qapp.exec_())
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was able to adapt this exactly to my needs, really appreciate your help